# Reference of a famous theorem of Topology is required

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, metric-spaces, compactness

The following is attributed to Hausdorff by a Professor of mine. I need to confirm the reference, in order incorporate in a book I am writing:
"A metric space is compact if and only if its complete and totally bounded."

Comment: You should find this statement in almost every book on general topology. Try to find it in Munkres book. I am sure you will find it.

Answer (score 1):

A place you might want to look at is one of Hausdorff's works called, Grundzüge der Mengenlehre, in English called Basics of Set Theory or Fundamentals of Set Theory. Even though it's called set theory, there were some topics on topology in it.